# change Scene background color in react-native-router-flux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-native-router-flux

This is the code I have in my router.js file (taken from [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/MINI_TUTORIAL.md) docs section):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import PageOne from './PageOne';
import PageTwo from './PageTwo';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Scene key="root">
          <Scene key="pageOne" component={PageOne} title="PageOne" initial={true} />
          <Scene key="pageTwo" component={PageTwo} title="PageTwo" />
        </Scene>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

[image]

How do I change the background color of the "header" (where "go back" arrow appears in the above image)?

I tried this way (adding `sceneStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'red'}}`):

```
<Scene key="pageTwo" component={PageTwo} title="PageTwo" sceneStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
```

but it seems to not be working.

FYI:

```
"react-native": "0.34.1",
"react-native-router-flux": "^3.35.0"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the library [API docs](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/b11a84962e4e4d9265770382b8859d21d1a12ea0/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md), you have to use navigationBarStyle property in order to change header style.

Try this instead :

```
<Scene key="pageTwo" component={PageTwo} title="PageTwo" navigationBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
```

Comment: Thank you, but I've just found the solution here: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/160.